# Cant set user status and log user amount from server in discord.js v12 after migrating from v11

Tags: javascript, api, discord

Confusing question i know right, but im having this issue after migrating from discord.js v11 to v12 with a bot for my friend.

Im having trouble with getting the amount of user(s) in a server,

Original Code (v11):

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`jthefibot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} servers.`);

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",
        game: {
            name: `jt.help for commands | Watching over the jTheFifthElement server with ${client.users.size} members.`,
            type: "Watching"
        }
    }); 
});
```

Starting bot on v12 throws this error: `"size" is not defined"`

So in my console i get "bot has started with undefined users in undefined channels" after migrating to v12, in v11, i'd normally get "Bot has started with (12) users in (x) channels"

Answer (score 0):

I just made a migration and had the same problem.

You have to replace :

```
client.users.size
```

by

```
client.users.cache.size
```

Add also `.cache` before `.channels` and `.guilds` for your other variables.

You can read the documentation here :
https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache